# Can you tftp download a file in one line?

Tags: tftp

I want to script the download of a file without having to enter tftp's command prompt. I've found that I can sort of achieve this with a here-document:

```
tftp 192.168.1.2 69 << _EOF_
  get testfile
  quit
_EOF
```

But I was hoping for something simpler, and closer to something as follows:

```
wget 192.168.1.2:69:/tftpboot/testfile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the Linux NetKit TFTP client.

H. Peter Anvin's TFTP client (in the `tftp-hpa` package in Debian) has a command line option `-c` that does what you want:

> #### `-c` command
>
> Execute `command` as if it had been entered on the `tftp` prompt.  Must be specified last on the command line.

Example:

```
tftp -m binary  "localhost"  -c get "pxelinux.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `tftp -g -r <filename> <ip-addr>` replace filename and ip-addr

Comment: not working on mac or ubuntu `sudo apt-get install tftp`.  which version are you using that can support those flags?

Comment: tftp -g -r  "busybox-armv7l" "192.168.1.3"